# How do I prevent a rewrite rule from executing for just one subdomain?

Tags: htaccess, apache, https, mod-rewrite, http

In the root level .htaccess I have added a condition to rewrite HTTP requests as HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This applies to the main domain and all subdomains. Unfortunately there is still work to do in one of the subdomains in order for it to work with HTTPS, so I would like to insert something into *that* one's .htaccess file to *undo* the inherited rewrite rules.

The file must still inherit a lot of other config from the parent domain, so it must only undo that one rewrite rule.

**How can I disable this rewrite rule for a particular subdomain?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subdomain points to a subdirectory off the main domain's document root then you can simply include a `RewriteEngine On` directive in that subdirectory's `.htaccess` file. However, this will override *all* the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file, which may not be desirable (although "other config from the parent domain" *will* be inherited).

If you have other mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` that you do want to run then you will need to add a condition to this HTTP to HTTPS rule in the parent `.htaccess` file that specifically excludes the subdomain.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Which says... if the *host* does *not* start `subdomain.` and is *not* https then...

You normally require the `L` flag on redirects so processing does not continue through the file (if you have more mod_rewrite directives). Also, this shopuld normally be a 301 (permanent) redirect. If this is the case then change the `302` to `301` when you are sure it's working OK. Although maybe best left as a 302 whilst this is being developed.

Also, no need to capture the URL-path (ie. `(.*)`) if this is not being used in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (or `RewriteCond` directives).

Comment: Excellent, well-thought-out answer! The bit about the RewriteRules overriding each other is particularly important.